# How can I add a space at the beginning of a <h1> in a v-for?

Tags: css, vuejs2

Consider the following simple code:

```
<div v-for="x in list" v-bind:key="x">
  <h1>{{ x }}</h1> | 
</div>
```

After the `h1` is closed, I write a blank space, a `|`, and a final blank space. That is, there should be *three* characters in between each `h1`. However, the final blank space is not read, and there only are two characters in between each `h1`. How can I force the document to read the final blank space?

Comment: HTML is made to ignore some whitespace characters. Maybe try `&nbsp;`?. Better use [CSS margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) and [CSS padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) Between margin and padding you can have a [border-right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-right) or simply surround that `|` with a span and give that some padding and/or margin.

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` instead of " ". It's a non-breaking space so that's what it is for.